# How retrofit is using okhttp and gson in this sample using dagger2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, dagger-2

***This is a working code***

**What I am trying to understand**:
How the retrofit uses things like `okhttp` , `gson` , `Cache` below .... I understand we inject it but as seen in `apimodule` i can see there is a global variable that is used by `retrofit` there but `gson` and `okhttp` are not globle how it is getting used

**Apimodule.java**

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    String mBaseUrl;

    ApiModule(String mBaseUrl) {
        this.mBaseUrl = mBaseUrl;
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.cache(cache);
        return client.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**ApiComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ApiModule.class})
public interface ApiComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ApiComponent mApiComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mApiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .apiModule(new ApiModule("https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/"))
                .build();
    }

    public ApiComponent getNetComponent() {
        return mApiComponent;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //injecting retrofit
    @Inject Retrofit retrofit;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getNetComponent().inject(this);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewHeroes);

        getHeroes();
    }

    private void getHeroes() {
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<List<Hero>> call = api.getHeroes();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Hero>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Hero>> call, Response<List<Hero>> response) {
                List<Hero> heroList = response.body();
                String[] heroes = new String[heroList.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < heroList.size(); i++) {
                    heroes[i] = heroList.get(i).getName();
                }

                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Hero>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using dagger, when we use `@Provide`, we are telling dagger how to create a specific `Dependency`, and this dependency is then available for any other object which requires that dependency. When we use `@Inject`, Dagger will then look what type of object is required, check which dependencies it requires, if this object you are trying to inject requires something which dagger already knows how to make (through something annotated with `@Provides`) it will then create a new instance of this dependency for that object, and continue this process until the entire object you request through inject has been made.

as an example :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideContext(app: YourApplication): Context = app

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideDatabase(context: Context): YourAppDb = YourAppDb.create(context)
```

in this example, whenever you request for an instance of  `YourAppDb`, dagger will check its dependencies, see that it requires `context`, it will check if it "knows" how to create context (check for something annotated with `@Provides`) and then use this `context` to make the database

Answer (score 0):

You provide OkHttp and Gson to Retrofit Builder, and then Retrofit uses them to make requests and parse JSON.

Comment: Yes but .... is it that in the generated classes `gson` and `okhttp` variables are global and thus getting used , because these are not global variables in `module` I have given

Comment: Well you are also not using retrofit directly. You are using them all through the Api class that you are creating.